# ORDER BY "CASE column" in JPA

Tags: jpa, jpql

I want to ORDER BY the case statement, is it possible? How can I do it?

```
SELECT new com.systemname.to.UserDataHolder(u.userId, 
CASE  WHEN (u.place.cityId = :cityId) THEN 1  WHEN (u.place.stateId = :stateId) THEN 2  ELSE 3 END)  
FROM User u 
ORDER BY u.userId DESC
```

Comment: Some advertising to change this for the JPA 3.0 spec: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jpa-api/issues/297

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What JPA provider are you using?

Try,

```
SELECT u.userId, 
(CASE  
    WHEN (u.place.cityId = :cityId) THEN 1
    WHEN (u.place.stateId = :stateId) THEN 2
    ELSE 3 END) as myNum
FROM User u 
ORDER BY u.userId, myNum DESC
```

or,

```
SELECT new com.systemname.to.UserDataHolder(u.userId, 
CASE  
    WHEN (u.place.cityId = :cityId) THEN 1
    WHEN (u.place.stateId = :stateId) THEN 2
    ELSE 3 END)
FROM User u 
ORDER BY u.userId, CASE  
    WHEN (u.place.cityId = :cityId) THEN 1
    WHEN (u.place.stateId = :stateId) THEN 2
    ELSE 3 END DESC
```

Comment: The second option works fine, but it takes longer than it should with only one CASE. What I did was, I setted the CASE value in Java, and I've put the CASE WHEN only on ORDER BY clause. It worked perfectly and faster than the old SQL that was on application.

Answer (score 0):

Not in a position to test right now so I'm not sure if this is valid syntax, but could you add an "AS" to it?

```
SELECT new com.systemname.to.UserDataHolder(u.userId, 
CASE  
    WHEN (u.place.cityId = :cityId) THEN 1
    WHEN (u.place.stateId = :stateId) THEN 2
    ELSE 3 END as myNum)
FROM User u 
ORDER BY u.userId, myNum DESC
```

Comment: No. At least this is not specified by the JPA (yet?). See https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jpa-api/issues/297